# Convert .csv into .xlsx but keeping data separated in columns

Tags: excel, vba

surely this question has been posted in the past, but I have not found it.
I am coding a Macro in order to get the information in a .csv data into my excel (.xlsm).
The code works pretty well. Converts the .csv into .xlsx and gets the information, but unfortunately, it pastes it almost everything in the same column. Whereas, when I save manually the .csv as .xlsx, it keeps the information as it is, separated in columns.

I paste the code, I hope someone can help me. Also, I hope someone gets some profit of some piece of it :)

Thank you very much in advance!*

```
Sub Main()

Dim FileAddress, FileName As String
Dim FolderAddress As String
Dim oldfname, newfname As String



Dim n, z, length As Integer

    FileAddress = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Capture name of current file
    myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    
    ' Set folder name to work through
    FolderAddress = Left(FileAddress, InStrRev(FileAddress, Application.PathSeparator))
    
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=FileAddress
    
    'xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    
    oldfname = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    newfname = FolderAddress & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4) & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=newfname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=newfName, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
    Kill oldfname
    Windows(myFileName).Activate
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook                               'Destination Workbook
    Set thisWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSV_Information")     'Destination Worksheet

    Set thatWB = Workbooks.Open(newfname)                   'Source xlsx
    
    FileNameFull = Right(newfname, Len(newfname) - InStrRev(newfname, "\"))
    FileNameDummy = Left(FileNameFull, (InStr(FileNameFull, ".") - 1))
    
    If Len(FileNameDummy) > 31 Then
    
            FileName = Left(FileNameDummy, 31)
    
        Else
    
            FileName = FileNameDummy
    
    End If
    
    
    Set thatWS = thatWB.Sheets(FileName)                   'Source Worksheet

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    thatWS.Range("A1:E1006").Copy
    thisWS.Range("A1:E1006").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    thatWB.Close
    
    n = Worksheets("CSV_Information").Range("A1:A1006").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    
    MsgBox n

    Worksheets("All_Transactions").Activate
    
    z = n + 1
    
    
    Worksheets("CSV_Information").Activate
    Range("A6:E" & z).Copy

    Worksheets("All_Transactions").Activate
    Range("5:6").Insert
    
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A6"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange Range("A6:E1006")
        .Header = xlNo
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: A guess: perhaps use the `Delimiter` and `Format` parameters of [`Workbooks.Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open)?

Comment: Answered you both in the comment below :)

Answer (score 0):

As @BigBen mentioned you can use the `Workbooks.Open` method to import the CSV data into Excel with the desired column separation.

You can try the following:

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim FileAddress As String
    Dim FolderAddress As String
    Dim myFileName As String
    Dim oldfname As String
    Dim newfname As String

    FileAddress = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Capture name of current file
    myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    ' Set folder name to work through
    FolderAddress = Left(FileAddress, InStrRev(FileAddress, Application.PathSeparator))

    ' Open the CSV file using Workbooks.Open with delimiter settings
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileAddress, Delimiter:="," ' Adjust delimiter as needed

    'xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    oldfname = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    newfname = FolderAddress & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4) & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=newfname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Kill oldfname
    Windows(myFileName).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, first of all, thank you both for your help. It was a really good idea, unfortunately it did not work. Maybe as a hint: Somehow I could test it in the office and it worked properly with that computer, but it does not at home. Also the macro shortcut (Alt+F11) does not work in my computer. Am I possibly missing some important setting here?

Comment: Well it could be a number of things. Things to consider on the computer you're using: macros are enabled in settings; both machines are running the same version of excel; file is saved with the ".xlsm" extension if it contains macros.

Comment: code updated to use Workbooks.Open vs Workbooks.OpenText

Comment: I have checked in the office, and the Excel version is the same, although it is quite possible that some setting is not. I have runned the program, and I have new info. When the information is sorted in different columns in the .csv, it is converted into .xlsx on only 1 column. On the other hand, when the .csv data is sorted only in 1 column, it converts it into .xlsx and sort it in different columns ( desired way ).

Comment: Hello, I already solved it!. The solution líes here: https://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files . It seems to be a conflict depending on region settings. Selecting english format solves this issue :)